# Why does setting XMLHttpRequest responseType before calling open throw?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, w3c, specifications

Running `new XMLHttpRequest().responseType = "json"` in the console throws an "InvalidStateError" exception in Firefox 26 and IE11 but not in Chrome 31.

Why?

[The Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#dom-xmlhttprequest-responsetype) states that setting `responseType`

> throws an "InvalidStateError" exception if the state is LOADING or DONE.

but in this case the state is UNSENT.

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a *working draft*, so it's normal if there are small differences or bugs in the implementations. I think Firefox still follows the behavior described in the [draft of August 2011](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20110816), where [is specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20110816/#the-responsetype-attribute) that the exception is thrown *if the state is not `OPENED` or `HEADERS_RECEIVED`*.

Answer (score 35):

Note that setting `responseType` *after* I call `open` on the xhr object solved my problem (using IE11)

Comment: From MS: "The timeout property may be set only in the time interval between a call to the open method and the first call to the send method."

Comment: Solved it for me. Got DOMException ABORT_ERR 20.
It's always an adventure with you, Mr. IE.

Comment: Exact details how his worked for me in IE: 1. set timeout after I call open. 2. set responseType="text/json" after I call open.

Comment: Edit: In MS Edge, you must set it *before* you call `open`