# adding password visibility to html page in esp32 wifi manager

Tags: html, server, esp32

I'm running the wifi manager [wifiConnect_Lite](https://github.com/smurf0969/WiFiConnect) on my esp32 so I don't have to hardcode my
wifi credentials. The problem I have is that the html webpage it launches to input your wifi credentials
doesn't have the "eye" option next to the password box to toggle visibility to verify input.
Does anybody know the code to do this. I'm ok with password being always visible if toggle
is problematic to implement. P.S. goes without saying I'm a young coder. I compile in ArduinoIDE (if it matters)
See html code below.

```
/*!
 * @file WC_AP_HTML.h
 *
 * HTML snippets to build the Access Point portal and the Parameters Portal.
 *
 * Written by Stuart Blair
 *
 * GNU General Public License v3.0 licence, all text here must be included in any redistribution and you should receive a copy of the license file.
 *
 */
 
#ifndef WC_AP_HTML
#define WC_AP_HTML ///< Define to stop re-inclusion
/*! \def char AP_HTTP_HEAD[] PROGMEM
Start of HTML output
 */
const char AP_HTTP_HEAD[] PROGMEM            = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no\"/><title>{v}</title>";
/*! \def AP_HTTP_STYLE[] PROGMEM 
Style for our access point 
*/
const char AP_HTTP_STYLE[] PROGMEM           = "<style type=\"text/css\">h1 { font-weight: normal; } .msgbox { font-size:1.2rem; line-height: 1.8em; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #ddffff; border-left: 6px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:1em; } .c{text-align:center}div,input{padding:5px;font-size:1em}input{width:95%;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px}body{text-align:center;font-family:verdana;}button{border:0;border-radius:.3rem;background-color:#1fa3ec;color:#fff;line-height:2.6rem;font-size:1.2rem;width:100%}.q{float:right;width:64px;text-align:right}.l{background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAMAAABEpIrGAAAALVBMVEX///8EBwfBwsLw8PAzNjaCg4NTVVUjJiZDRUUUFxdiZGSho6OSk5Pg4eFydHTCjaf3AAAAZElEQVQ4je2NSw7AIAhEBamKn97/uMXEGBvozkWb9C2Zx4xzWykBhFAeYp9gkLyZE0zIMno9n4g19hmdY39scwqVkOXaxph0ZCXQcqxSpgQpONa59wkRDOL93eAXvimwlbPbwwVAegLS1HGfZAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) no-repeat left center;background-size:1em;}.cfail,.cok{text-align:center; font-size:1.2rem; line-height: 2em; margin-top: 1em; padding: 0.7em; display:none;} .cfail{color: #FFFFFF;background-color: #ff8433;} .cok{ background-color: #6aff33;}</style>";
/** Scripts for our page */
const char AP_HTTP_SCRIPT[] PROGMEM          = "<script>function c(l){document.getElementById('s').value=l.innerText||l.textContent;document.getElementById('p').focus();}</script>";
/** End of the header section and beginning of the body */
const char AP_HTTP_HEAD_END[] PROGMEM        = "</head><body><div style='text-align:left;display:inline-block;min-width:260px;'>";
/** Start of our HTMl configuration Form */
const char AP_HTTP_PORTAL_OPTIONS[] PROGMEM  = "<div class=\"msgbox\">Connect this device to a WiFi network. Select the option to find a WiFi network.</div><form action=\"/wifi\" method=\"get\"><button>Configure WiFi (Auto Scan)</button></form><br/><form action=\"/0wifi\" method=\"get\"><button style=\"background-color:#bbbbbb;\">Configure WiFi (Manual)</button></form><!--<br/><form action=\"/i\" method=\"get\"><button>Info</button></form><br/></form>-->";
/** HTML snippet for wifi scanning */
const char AP_HTTP_ITEM[] PROGMEM            = "<div><a href='#p' onclick='c(this)'>{v}</a>&nbsp;<span class='q {i}'>{r}%</span></div>";
/** HTML form for saving wifi connection details */
const char AP_HTTP_FORM_START[] PROGMEM      ="<form method=\"post\" action=\"wifisave\"><label>Enter WiFi Name ('SSID'):</label><input id=\"s\" name=\"s\" length=32 placeholder=\"Example: Home_Network_2002\"><label>Enter WiFi Password:</label><input id=\"p\" name=\"p\" length=64 type=\"password\" placeholder=\"Password123\"><br/>";;
/** HTML snippet for our custom parameters */
const char AP_HTTP_FORM_PARAM[] PROGMEM      = "<br/><input id='{i}' name='{n}' maxlength={l} placeholder='{p}' value='{v}' {c}>";
/** The end of our HTML Form */
const char AP_HTTP_FORM_END[] PROGMEM        = "<br/><button type='submit'>Save and Connect</button></form>";
/** HTML snippet to recan for networks */
const char AP_HTTP_SCAN_LINK[] PROGMEM       = "<br/><div class=\"c\"><a href=\"/wifi\">Re-scan</a></div>";
/** HTML snippet for saved confirmation */
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760635/why-does-setting-xmlhttprequest-responsetype-before-calling-open-throw
// https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html
// https://javascript-minifier.com/

/* Use JavaScript to ping the ESP periodically @ the AP IP address. 
 * If it comes back as an AP again then we know the connection to the WiFi didn't work. 
 * We wait about 30 seconds to determine this outcome. This isn't 100% foolproof, but should be good enough.
*/
/*
<script type="text/javascript">
function doPing() {        
        //if ( timeout_count > 20 ) {
        if ( attempt_count > 20 ) { // wait about a minute
            window.clearInterval(myPinger), document.getElementById("conn_ok").style.display = "block"
        }
        
        var o = new XMLHttpRequest;
        o.onload = function() {
            console.log(this.responseText), document.getElementById("conn_fail").style.display = "block", window.clearInterval(myPinger)
        }, o.ontimeout = function(o) {
            console.log("Timeout Counter is: " + timeout_count++)
        }, o.open("GET", "/foo"), o.timeout = 1000, o.send(null), console.log("Ping counter is: " + attempt_count++)
    }
    
    attempt_count = 0;
    timeout_count = 0;
    var myPinger = window.setInterval(doPing, 3000);

</script>
*/
const char AP_HTTP_SAVED[] PROGMEM           = "<div>Credentials Saved.<br />Attempting to connect to  WiFi network. Please wait.... <br /><script type=\"text/javascript\">function doPing(){attempt_count>20&&(window.clearInterval(myPinger),document.getElementById(\"conn_ok\").style.display=\"block\");var t=new XMLHttpRequest;t.onload=function(){console.log(this.responseText),document.getElementById(\"conn_fail\").style.display=\"block\",window.clearInterval(myPinger)},t.ontimeout=function(t){console.log(\"Timeout Counter is: \"+timeout_count++)},t.open(\"GET\",\"/foo\"),t.timeout=1e3,t.send(null),console.log(\"Ping counter is: \"+attempt_count++)}attempt_count=0,timeout_count=0;var myPinger=window.setInterval(doPing,3e3);</script><div class=\"cok\" id=\"conn_ok\">Connected to {ap} !<br />You may now close this window. </div><div class=\"cfail\" id=\"conn_fail\">Failed to connect to {ap}!<br /><a href=\"/\">Click here</a> to try again.</div></div>";
/** End of the HTML page */
const char AP_HTTP_END[] PROGMEM             = "</div></body></html>";
/** HTML snippet for our custom parameters portal form */
const char AP_HTTP_PORTAL_PARAM_OPTIONS[] PROGMEM  = "<form action=\"/params\" method=\"get\"><button>Configure Parameters</button></form><br/><form action=\"/i\" method=\"get\"><button>Info</button></form><br/>";
/** HTML snippet for our custom parameters save */
const char AP_HTTP_FORM_PARAM_START[] PROGMEM      ="<form method=\"get\" action=\"wifisave\">";

#endif
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with ESP32 or server, it is html/css. See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp